# Monitoring tools for Azure application error logs

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-log-analytics

Are there any opensource/commercial tools available which monitors and notifies the team about the errors logged in the Azure webapp error logs.

Edit: require an email as soon as error logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Application Insights.

You can log and monitor web **server diagnostics** and **application diagnostics**.

**Application diagnostics**

Application diagnostics allows you to capture information produced by a web application. ASP.NET applications can use the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` class to log information to the application diagnostics log. For example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("If you're seeing this, something bad happened");
```

To enable diagnostics in the [Azure Porta](https://portal.azure.com/)l, go to the blade for your web app and click Settings > Diagnostics logs.

When you enable application diagnostics you also choose the Level. This setting allows you to filter the information captured to informational, warning or error information. Setting this to verbose will log all information produced by the application.

**Alerts**

In Application Insights, you can [create custom metric alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-alerts). You could set up an alert on the Metric 'Exception Rate' and set up an email address as a notification point.

**Articles**

Here is a good [article](https://msftplayground.com/2017/02/trace-listeners-logging-azure-application-insights/) on this topic on how to use Application Insights and Trace listeners.

Comment: Thanks aaronR, Alerts are import for me. as soon as an error logs it should send an email.

Comment: You can configure that any way you want. I have mine set to send me an alert if I have more than 3 exceptions in a 5 min interval.

Comment: which metric should i select ? in my case exception is handled and written to logs using System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError

Comment: Do you mean which Metric? I use Source ->alert on 'Metrics' and selected the metric 'Exception rate' and set a condition and Threshold.

Comment: I have set an Alert based on Metric: Exception Rate , Condition: Greater than or equal to , Threshold 1, Period: Over the last 5 minutes - For some reason I didn't receive any notification.

Comment: Did you trigger any logic that would cause and exception?

Comment: Yes..    try
            {
                int i = 0;
                var k = 3 / i;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Trace.TraceError(ex.StackTrace);
            }

Comment: Are you seeing any information being tracked for the application insights account tied to the web app?

Comment: No.. but i can see the exceptions logged using log stream

Comment: You need to make sure the Application Insights is configured and reporting basic statistics.

Comment: Can you please explain basic configuration required for this scenario ?

Comment: You need to follow these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net

Comment: Is there a way i can configure in App insights without touching or adding libraries to the code

Comment: No you need to follow the steps outlined